# Android Facebook SDK - Share dialog does not respond to cancel callback

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm working with Facebook sdk 4.0 on my android app and I found this problem:

-when I share a post, I can see the facebook interface and I can post it and cancel it perfectly. I registered the callbacks, but if I press the cancel button, the onCancel callback is not called, the post is not published, but the onSuccess callback is called. However, if I touch the close button, everything works ok.

Here is my code:

```
 private void fbOnShare(){

    ShareLinkContent shareContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentTitle("The Simpson!")
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.foxplay.com/ar/show/6980-los-simpson?gclid=CPa-7N-y7MUCFYMSHwodNLYAKQ"))
            .build();


    this._btnShare = (ShareButton)findViewById(R.id.share_button);
    this._btnShare.setShareContent( shareContent );


    _btnShare.registerCallback( this._fbCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {

            Log.v("MyApp", "Share success!"); //Showed if I press the share or the cancel button

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.v("MyApp", "Share canceled"); //Only showed when I press the close button
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.v("MyApp","Share error: " + e.toString());
        }

    });
}
```

The _fbCallbackManager is created in another method that initializes everything in the onCreate method from the activity.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGoeZ.jpg

The "Cancelar" button only respond to the onSuccess callback inspite of does not post the share content. The "close" button works ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [THIS](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/890116221030179/) it is not a bug and it should stay that way.

The only way to know if the user accepted the publishing is to check for the postID on the result.

You will only have a postID if the user didn't cancel AND if the user is logged in to your app AND it has publish permissions. Otherwise it will always be null.

Yeah I know, it sucks.

Comment: So when you mean the user is logged in to your app and has publish permissions, does that mean that I need to log them in before using Facebooks ShareButton or will it do this when it opens up the share dialog. I am wondering if I am not getting this because I have not fully setup my app on the developer dashboard or if I need to log the user in before allowing them to use the "ShareButton".

Comment: It depends on how you are implementing the ShareButton. Usually the share button just share anything to Facebook without the need to register to your app. The user needs only to login to facebook. But you can implement everything you need on the button. When the button is activated, if you have a registration token, you send him to the publish page, if not, you start the login to your app process and after the result, show the share page. HTH

Comment: Okay, I thought part of the reason to use the ShareButton was to avoid having to log the user in on your app, but it sounds like this limits the functionality for the user. Thanks for the reply, unfortunately it was not what I wanted to hear.

Comment: Even if my link is posted on Fb I get postID null using `ShareDialog`

Answer (score 2):

```
private boolean hasPublishPermission()
    {
        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

        return accessToken != null && accessToken.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
    }

private void postStatusUpdate()
    {
        if(hasPublishPermission())
        {
            Log.d("PostStatus", "Ist");
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
            .setContentDescription( "The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/docs/android"))
            .build();
            if(ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class))
            {
                Log.d("PostStatus", "2nd");
                ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(instance);
                shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, shareCallback);

            }
            else if (profile != null) 
            {
                Log.d("PostStatus", "3rdt");
                ShareApi.share(linkContent, shareCallback);
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
        }

    }



private FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result> shareCallback = new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>()
                    {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Result result) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
                    };
```

Comment: accessToken.getPermissions() always returns 0.

Comment: @Dpedrinha accessToken.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions") give a true condition if you have already take this permission otherwise false

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that problem is happening only with who is also working with Parse. But any way, your code doesn't work as he wants. It will always call onSuccess even if the user does not share what the app wants. Check my answer please, and correct me if I'm wrong.